# OpenCL in Haskell only processing some elements of the input array

Tags: c, haskell, opencl

So I'm trying to use `OpenCL` in Haskell, but it seems it's only processing half of the list I give it, placing a 0 between each element then only processing the first `n` elements, ie: list I give it:`[1,2,3,4,5,6]` the list it sees: `[1,0,2,0,3,0]`. I'm using the `OpenCL` package from `cabal` and `AMD`'s `OpenCL library version 2.9-1.`

OpenCL Kernel code (C):

```
int power(int a, int n, int mod)
{
    int power = a;
    int result = 1;

    while (n)
    {
        if (n & 1)
            result = (result * power) % mod;
        power = (power * power) % mod;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}

bool witness(int n, int s, int d, int a)
{
    int x = power(a, d, n);
    int y;

    while (s) {
        y = (x * x) % n;
        if (y == 1 && x != 1 && x != n - 1)
            return 0;
        x = y;
        --s;
    }
    if (y != 1)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int is_prime_mr(int n)
{
    if (((!(n & 1)) && n != 2) || (n < 2) || (n % 3 == 0 && n != 3))
        return 0;
    if (n <= 3)
        return 1;

    int d = n / 2;
    int s = 1;
    while (!(d & 1)) {
        d /= 2;
        ++s;
    }

    if (n < 1373653)
        return witness(n, s, d, 2) && witness(n, s, d, 3);
    if (n < 9080191)
        return witness(n, s, d, 31) && witness(n, s, d, 73);
    if (n < 4759123141)
        return witness(n, s, d, 2) && witness(n, s, d, 7) && witness(n, s, d, 61);
    if (n < 1122004669633)
        return witness(n, s, d, 2) && witness(n, s, d, 13) && witness(n, s, d, 23) && witness(n, s, d, 1662803);
    if (n < 2152302898747)
        return witness(n, s, d, 2) && witness(n, s, d, 3) && witness(n, s, d, 5) && witness(n, s, d, 7) && witness(n, s, d, 11);
    if (n < 3474749660383)
        return witness(n, s, d, 2) && witness(n, s, d, 3) && witness(n, s, d, 5) && witness(n, s, d, 7) && witness(n, s, d, 11) && witness(n, s, d, 13);
    return witness(n, s, d, 2) && witness(n, s, d, 3) && witness(n, s, d, 5) && witness(n, s, d, 7) && witness(n, s, d, 11) && witness(n, s, d, 13) && witness(n, s, d, 17);
}

__kernel void duparray(__global int *in, __global int *out )
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);

    if(id == 1)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", in[i]);
        }
    }

    //printf("%d :: %d\t\t",id, in[id]*2);
    out[id] = (is_prime_mr(in[id]) == 0) ? 0 : in[id];
    //out[id] = in[id];
}
```

Haskell code:

```
import Control.Parallel.OpenCL
import Foreign( castPtr, nullPtr, sizeOf )
import Foreign.C.Types( CFloat )
import Foreign.Marshal.Array( newArray, peekArray )
import System.IO

upper = 200
lower = 0

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- Initialize OpenCL
  (platform:_) <- clGetPlatformIDs
  (dev:_) <- clGetDeviceIDs platform CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL
  context <- clCreateContext [CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM platform] [dev] print
  q <- clCreateCommandQueue context dev []


  handle <- openFile "gpuPrimalityTest.c" ReadMode
  programSource <- hGetContents handle

  -- Initialize Kernel
  program <- clCreateProgramWithSource context (programSource)
  clBuildProgram program [dev] ""
  kernel <- clCreateKernel program "duparray"

  -- Initialize parameters
  let original = [lower .. upper] :: [Int]
      elemSize = sizeOf (0 :: Int)
      vecSize = elemSize * length original
  -- putStrLn $ "Original array = " ++ show original
  input  <- newArray original

  mem_in <- clCreateBuffer context [CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR] (vecSize, castPtr input)  
  mem_out <- clCreateBuffer context [CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY] (vecSize, nullPtr)

  clSetKernelArgSto kernel 0 mem_in
  clSetKernelArgSto kernel 1 mem_out

  -- Execute Kernel
  eventExec <- clEnqueueNDRangeKernel q kernel [length original] [] []

  -- Get Result
  eventRead <- clEnqueueReadBuffer q mem_out True 0 vecSize (castPtr input) [eventExec]

  result <- peekArray (length original) input
  putStrLn $ "Result array = " ++ show (filter (\x -> x/=0) result)

  return ()
```

For the Haskell code I'm using a modified version of the first example in the Github for the OpenCL package I'm using: https://github.com/IFCA/opencl

And I also kept the traces I had in the OpenCL kernel. Those 2 `printf`'s are how I was attempting to debug this.

Any help is appreciated

Edit: It seems to work when I use `32` bit ints

Comment: What happens if you use `Int32` instead of `Int` in your host code?

Comment: Wow, I would never have thought the issue was the binary data being sent to the kernel. Changing it to be a 32 bit int seemed to fix that issue, thank you

Comment: @jprice You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the data layout of the buffers in your host code matches what the device expects. This can be achieved in your example code by using `Int32` instead of `Int`.

Comment: You should use `CInt` for this purpose, it's the type which is guaranteed to be compatible (via Storable) with the C `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

Using `long` worked for me:

`__kernel void duparray(__global long *in, __global long *out )`

Comment: When providing an answer to an older question with existing answers it is useful to explain how your answer differs. What are the benefits of using long over cint?

Comment: Thank you Jason Aller, sloppy me... 'cint' did not work in my version of the code. So I tried 'long'. That did work, so it's more of an extra option.
(Maybe I should ask the question why 'cint' didn't work in my situation?)